# How do I write a program that both accepts commandline arguments with argparse and accepts arguments to objects created from class?

Tags: python, argparse

How do I write a program that both accepts commandline arguments with `argparse` and accepts arguments to `__init__` so the program can be used outside the commandline? I'm also wondering if I need to use `os.getcwd()` explicitly when exporting a file. Thanks so much for the help!

```
class MyClass(object):
     def __init__(self, file='', duplicate_column_name='', file_destination=''):
         self.__file1 = file
         self.__duplicate = duplicate_column_name
         self.__file_dest = file_destination


    if __name__ == __main__:
         parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=True, description="Allows users to filter CSV file in a variety of ways.")
         parser.add_argument('-f', action='store', dest = 'file', help='Store the name of the csv file you want converted')
         parser.add_argument('-c', action='store', dest = 'column', help='Store the name of the column you want filtered.')
         parser.add_argument('-d', action='store', dest = 'file_destination', default= str( os.getcwd() ) + "/filteredcsvfile.csv", help= "Store the name of the file you'd like the program to create")

         if len(sys.argv) <= 2:
             parser.print_help()
             sys.exit(1)

         cmd_args = parser.parse_args()
         file = cmd_args.file
         duplicate_column_name = cmd_args.column
         file_destination = cmd_args.file_destination
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You cut off the class statement... what is your class suppose to do?

Comment: `def __init__(self,` suggests a class... Can you mock up a small example class and post it? The `if __name__ == __main__:` shouldn't be in the class, it should be dedented to module level.

Comment: What doesn't work? Can't you just import the module and use it? The problem may be in how python installs modules. Top level scripts (`__main__`) are placed somewhere in the operating systems' `PATH` so they can be executed while importable modules go somewhere in python's module path. What problem are you having?

Comment: Apart from above comments, please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to refine your question for help.

Comment: Have you tried `MyClass(file, duplicate_column_name, file_destination)`?

Comment: Sorry I took so long to respond. I figured out how to fix my problem and I didn't realize that Stack Overflow wouldn't e-mail me when people responded. I ended up doing what hpaulj said. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Here is a full example of my code. I'm still having trouble debugging my code.